# Iterate the methods of a specified class

Tags: python

Suppose such a mininal Mixin which group multiple methods

```
class Mixin:
    "Iterate methods"
    def strip():
        return str.strip

    def title():
        return str.title

    def swapcase():
        return str.swapcase
```

The the methods to deal with a snippet of text

```
content = "iterate methods  "
content = Mixin.strip()(content)
content = Mixin.title()(content)
content = Mixin.swapcase()(content)
print(content)
```

I refacotr the codes as:

```
ops = [Mixin.strip(), Mixin.title(), Mixin.swapcase()]
for function in ops:
    content = function(content)
print(content)
```

I wonder how could simplify it as

```
for function in Mixin:
    content = function(content)
print(content)
```

I tried dir(Mixin) but it's not satisfying.

```
In [33]: [method for method in dir(Mixin) if not method.startswith("__")]
Out[33]: ['strip', 'swapcase', 'title']`
```

Comment: Your `Mixin` is not acting like a mixin, or like a class at all. You have a bunch of methods that don't take `self`, which you call by relying on the fact that unbound methods are implemented as regular functions. So, why not just use a list, or an `OrderedDict`, or a `namedtuple`, or something else?

Comment: Meanwhile: the methods of a class are defined to be in arbitrary order. If you really want to, you can use a metaclass to force them to be in some specified order (e.g., see the `OrderedClass` recipe in PEP 3115), but this is going pretty far out of your way to (mis)use a class when really all you want is a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with abarnert, this seems like a weird use for a class / Mixin. But instead of questioning your use case, as partial answer to your question, you can use `getattr`.

`getattr` allows you to get the attribute of an object given its name.

So, for example:

```
for method in (attr for attr in dir(Mixin) if not attr.startswith('__')):
    content = getattr(Mixin, method)()(content)
```

But, given the fact that the iteration doesn't have an specific order, then the result might not be deterministic.

The best way is to use an specific order, for example:

```
for method in ['strip', 'title', 'swapcase']:
    content = getattr(Mixin, method)()(content)
```

Comment: Don't use `dir` here. It is mostly meant as a debugging function for use in an interactive interpreter session. In fact, it's not guaranteed to  return anything useful 
 Use `vars` to get the attributes of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think Havok's answer is very good but since juanpa.arrivillaga said it's not good to use `dir` here i have a solution not using `dir`, using `vars`:

```
class Mixin:
    "Iterate methods"
    def strip(s):
        return s.strip()

    def title(s):
        return s.title()

    def swapcase(s):
        return s.swapcase()

content = "iterate methods   "
for function in reversed([i for i in vars(Mixin) if not i.startswith('_')]):
    content = getattr(Mixin, function)(content)
print(content)
```

Output:

```
Iterate Methods
```

Comment: This is not a good use case for `exec`. And you shouldn't use `dir`, use `vars`. `dir` is meant for debugging .

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your comment, now i know `exec` and `dir` shouldn't be used here